# Change Extension Top-most Context Menu Title

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

Currently the top-most context menu for my extension uses the `manifest.json` `name` as the title. The `name` is rather long and creates a large context menu to fit it. Is it possible to change the title that the context menu uses? I would prefer it use the `manifest.json` `short_name`.

I was not able to find anything in [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus) that mentioned doing this.

Example:

## manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "My extension - And a blurb",
    "short_name": "My extension"
    ...
    "permissions": [
      "contextMenus"
    ],
    "icons": {
      "16": "icon-bitty.png",
      "48": "icon-small.png",
      "128": "icon-large.png"
    },
    ...
  }
```

## background.js

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Test item"});
```

---

Results in a context menu that looks like:

```
My extension - And a blurb
|
--- Test item
```

I want it to be:

```
My extension
|
--- Test item
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Basically, if we are going to investigate this, and to understand *exactly* what you are talking about, a [mcve] would go a long way to making it easier.  In addition, a small screen capture to indicate *exactly* what you are talking about would be helpful. I can *guess* at what you are talking about, and I believe I know, but I don't *know* I am right in my understanding as to which context menu you are talking about.

Comment: Your example shouldn't produce this. If that's really all you do, it should create a top level item, not a submenu.

Comment: You are correct. I didn't test my example and just assumed that it worked like my real solution. Your answer solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior happens only if you have more than 1 menu item and don't take care of your own hierarchy.

If you declare your own "root" item, and all other items are explicitly inside it, this won't happen.

```
chrome.contextMenus.removeAll();
chrome.contextMenus.create({title: "How fancy", id: "root"});
chrome.contextMenus.create({title: "Indeed", id: "sub1", parentId: "root"});
chrome.contextMenus.create({title: "Indubitably", id: "sub2", parentId: "root"});
```

will result in

```
[your 16x16 icon] How fancy
|
+- Indeed
|
+- Indubitably
```

In general, make sure you assign IDs to your context menus. It's useful for many purposes.

*Note: technically, `contextMenus` is an asynchronous API and one should, ideally, chain the calls instead of simply sequencing them, but a sequence of calls to the same asynchronous API seems to work fine in this case. If you need to run code after all menus were added, do it in a callback of last `create`.*